# jquery find out if any of the elements has the attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to find out if any of the elements with same classes has the attribute value that i specified

ex.

```
    if ($('.elem').attr('category') == 'meat') {
        alert('');
    }
```

some elements with the same classes can have an attribute: category="fruits" . . becuase I used classes to select the elements, It returns multiple results i want to find out if any of them has ex. the attribute meat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute selector like this.

```
$(".elem[category='meat']").length
```

This will select all the elements with category meat and classname .elem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
if ($('.elem').is('[category="meat"]')) {
    alert('');
}
```